# Drawing Volumes and Surfaces into Wires

Tags: differential-geometry

A volume can be expressed as a differentiable bijection  in the form of a surface [manifold]. Why can't we have an analogous differentiable bijection of a surface to a line or a curve?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the setup more. You certainly can't do this in general even for $3$-manifolds (solids) into $2$-manifolds (surfaces), since if the domain is compact than such a differentiable bijection would be a homeomorphism, and hence cannot exist by dimension considerations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.The function f(x,y,x,p)=c ;c =constant has three independent coordinates as of free 3D space. It may be considered to be a surface embedded in a 4D volume just as x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2 is a 2D surface embedded in  a 3D volume.In relativity if the four dimensional manifold is considered as a surface then it necessitates embedding in 5D space.The manifold is a meshwork of curves –one dimensional objects embedded in 4 dimensional space.   In parallel transport we consider transporting a 4D vector over the manifold treated as  surface.

Comment: (in continuation)By applying a constraint we can derive a 3D surface embedded in 4D space and execute the  parallel transport a 4D vector on some curve on this 3D surface obtained by the constraint. In such a situation the vector may protrude into or out of the 3D surface created, staying confined to 4D space.When we come to the curvature elements we do have the impression of a surface. But this interpretation is not mandatory.

Comment: (in continuation)In deriving the notion of the Christoffel symbols, the Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor and the Ricci scalar we do not use the concept of an object of zero thickness like a surface. They are derived independent of any surface interpretation of the manifold.  Nevertheless  the surface picture---4D surface embedded in a 5D volume conjures up the physical notion of curvature in a palpable manner. The surface  picture of the manifold or embedding in higher dimensions,at least in the light of the issues discussed, is not a mandatory consideration.

Comment: If we try to embed a surface in a higher dimensional object we we do not attempt a homeomorphism between the higher dimensional space and the embedded surface